# How to numerically find Floquet multipliers (e.g., characteristic multipliers or Lyapunov exponents for periodic orbits from chaotic systems)?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Anyone have any suggestions for the following situation/question? (help wanted, please!)

I understand the theory (c.f., Perko or Nayfeh and Balachandran, Ch.3), but I do not understand how this is accomplished numerically:

Given a (chaotic) dynamical system (for example, I am using the Lorenz system with standard parameters), if I have numerically found (stabilized) an unstable periodic orbit, how would I find the UPO's Floquet multiplier?  Note that since the system is nonlinear, there is no explicit formula for the UPOs.  In the big picture, what I am trying to do is investigate the various calculations on a chaotic system (dimension, natural measure, etc) that can be approximated by having obtained this information from UPOs (e.g., its numerical stability or Lyapunov exponent).

I am aware that similar questions have been asked here on Stack Exchange:

[How to calculate floquet exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274899/how-to-calculate-floquet-exponents)

[Finding Floquet Multipliers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68439/finding-floquet-multipliers)

but in neither thread is this process demonstrated numerically.  The examples in my textbooks all assume an explicit formula for the periodic orbit.  Once again, I understand the theory, but not its practice, especially in my case when I do not have an explicit formula for the UPO, just a $(N\times 3)$ matrix of orbit time steps ($N$ is the number of time steps from my UPO solver).  I am familiar with *Matlab*, *C/C++*, and *Python*.

Thank you!

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Although this question is several months old, no one has yet to provide a response.  Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Suggestions, anyone??!

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem?